# Refine data elements using having clause tsql

Tags: t-sql, aggregate, having

I'm trying to pull a dataset that returns records ONLY when there are two QUALIFERs present. I've tried left joins, populating data in temp tables then manipulating something, then numerous having clauses (resulting in subquery selects, and additional groups). I would appreciate any assistance on what I can do further.

Query:

```
Select E,  CASE WHEN QUALIFER = '1' THEN 'NAME1' WHEN QUALIFER = '2' then 'NAME2' ELSE 'FINALNAME' END AS TYPE, count(rt.ID) 'Number '
from TABLE_ONE  co (nolock) 
join TABLE_TWO rt (nolock) 
on co.ID = rt.ID
   where co.E in (select * from #tempEmail)
AND convert(date,co.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP)between '1/1/2020' and '8/15/2020'
AND TRANS_STATUS = 'APPROVED'

group by E, QUALIFER
order by E, QUALIFER
```

Current resultset:

```
E                       TYPE    Number
FAKEEMAIL1@Gmail        NAME1   1
FAKEEMAIL1@Gmail        NAME2   1
otheremailj@gmail.com   Name1   21
```

Desired resultset:

```
E                   TYPE    Number
FAKEEMAIL1@Gmail    NAME1   1
FAKEEMAIL1@Gmail    NAME2   1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the below query. I used a temp table to make things more simple for my mind.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#email') is not null drop table #email
create table #email
(
    email varchar(50),
    typeValue varchar(15),
    Number int
)


insert into #email(email, typeValue, Number)
Select 
    E,  
    CASE WHEN QUALIFER = '1' THEN 'NAME1' WHEN QUALIFER = '2' then 'NAME2' ELSE 'FINALNAME' END AS TYPE, 
    count(rt.ID) 'Number '
from TABLE_ONE  co (nolock) 
join TABLE_TWO rt (nolock) 
on co.ID = rt.ID
where co.E in (select * from #tempEmail)
AND convert(date,co.INSERTED_TIMESTAMP)between '1/1/2020' and '8/15/2020'
AND TRANS_STATUS = 'APPROVED'
group by E, QUALIFER


select a.email, a.typeValue
from #email a
inner join
(
select email, typeValue, rank() over (partition by email order by typeValue) as typeCount
from #email t
 ) as b
 on b.email = a.email
 and b.typeCount > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but that won't work. If a single email has 15 records, but only one qualifier, then in this instance, the email count is 15, but the Qualifier is still 1. so the undesired record will still return. Ex. fakeun1212e@gmail.com NAME1 12

Comment: This won't work because I'm pulling the TYPE in the grouping, so each clause only returns 1. but considering and OR... if an email has more than 1 record then it would still return.

 having (count(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'NAME1' THEN 1 END) >1  AND (count(CASE WHEN TYPE IS NULL THEN 0 END)>1)

Comment: Ah I see, I did not realize that was a need.  I adjusted the answer above.